# Inspecting a particular kind of 3D scene

Tags: three.js

Consider the case of a large and complex 3D assembly model composed of many objects. I would like to inspect it in the following way:

- Load the assembly into the scene
- Point a camera at it and set things up so that the assembly is fully visible and centered on the screen
- Visually inspect the assembly by rotating/panning/magnifying it as a single unit using the mouse. I don't need to move the individual objects (constituting the assembly) independently. Please note, I would like the camera to be fixed. The movements are to be applied to the assembly as a whole. There are several Controls provided in three.js but they all seem to apply to the camera.
- Can someone suggest a way to do this? For instance, can the existing Controls be tied to something other than a camera?

Comment: What is the motivation behind moving the objects instead of the camera? The standard when rotating/panning/zooming with a mouse, as you noted, is moving the camera and there are reasons to that.

Comment: The idea was to shine a light straight ahead onto the object and have different parts of it come under the light as the object is rotated. But I suppose the same effect could be achieved with less computation by moving the camera and light together, while keeping the object stationary. Does three.js offer a way to couple a camera and light?  @Berthur

Comment: I see. Well your initial idea is probably fine, but I don't happen to know by heart how to correctly use e.g. OrbitControls on an object that is not the camera. You could do some experimentation.
As for your second idea, yes you can e.g. add lights as childen of the camera, and add the camera to the scene, to make them always be in the same reference frame as the camera.

Comment: Sounds like you’re looking for transform controls: https://threejs.org/examples/?q=controls#misc_controls_transform